# Add button to copy Excel rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I want to add a button on a row in a spreadsheet that copies the contents from one cell to another if and when I click the button. I already have found the code to do this, however, I want to be able to copy the button to a new row and have it work on that row, with the cells on that row, without having to go in and change the code.

This code below is the one I have, but it is specific to the one row it is written for only:

```
Sub CopyValue()

    ActiveSheet.Range("O7").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("K7")
    ActiveSheet.Range("R7").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("N7")

End Sub
```

and copies `K7` cell contents to `O7` cell contents etc.

If I copy the button o the next row it doesn't work for that row unless I go in and change the code, which means adding a new button or macro name and code to do so.

I want to just copy and add a row below again and again, and have it work on that row.
Cell formulas work this way, but how do I trigger a cell formula with a click of a button on the same row?

I need to be able to do this on hundreds or more rows, just by copying and pasting, or duplicating the row, or copying and pasting the button to a new row.

I have Excel 2007.

Comment: Does your application require that you have a button? Would it work to have the user click a cell on the row to be affected instead? Code for that would be very simple to implement.

Comment: Yes I can use a cell, and that would be good, however I don't know what code to add to a cell yet to do this, as I assume it will be different to the code below.

Comment: I have this so far for a cell as a button:

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
            'code here as if it were your Button_Click event.
                MsgBox "Instant button!"
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: I need to work out how to click a button on row 7 etc and copy the value from col K7 to col O7 and col N7 to col R7.
That is it. Need to just be able to copy the button and paste it into that spot on any row, and have it work for that row individually as well. So I can basically add that cell to every row on my spreadsheet and it works for each individual row. 

Look forward to your reply

Thanks for your time and willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following VBA code to accomplish your goal much more easily than generating code for individual ActiveX or Form Control buttons.

The following VBA allows the user to double-click a cell in a designated column (the "button column") and the code will copy the values *on the same row the user double-clicked* from the source to destination columns you specify.  This code works on all rows in your worksheet without requiring you to modify the code in any way.

Don't be thrown off by the code's repeated references to cells on row 1 (e.g. `O1` and `K1`). In each of these cases, the `.Column` property is used because we're only interested in the *column* in question. The row that will be manipulated is always the same row the user double-clicks.

In the Excel VBA Editor (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open) navigate to your worksheet's module, then paste in the following code:

```
Private Sub
Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo Quit
'Copy values between columns on same row that user double-clicks

'Quit if Target range includes more than one cell
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

With ActiveSheet

    'Here, specify the worksheet column the user can double-click to activate this
    'routine.  For the "B" column, in the Range method specify cell "B1" (all cells
    'in column will be used, not just that on row 1).
    If Target.Column = .Range("B1").Column Then
        .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("O1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("K1").Column)
        .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("R1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("N1").Column)

        Cancel = True   'Cancel the double-click
    End If

    'Here you can specify a second "button column" with its own set of copy actions.
    If Target.Column = .Range("C1").Column Then
        .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("E1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("F1").Column)
        .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("G1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("H1").Column)

        Cancel = True   'Cancel the double-click
    End If

End With

Quit:
End Sub
```

As written, the code will be triggered when the user double-clicks any cell in column `B`.  To change this, modify this line of code to point to the column you wish to act as your "button column":

```
If Target.Column <> .Range("B1").Column Then Exit Sub
```

The rest of the code should be self-explanatory, but ask any questions you have.

**Edit:** I changed the VBA to permit *two* button columns, each able to copy values between different source and destination columns.

Comment: If I add acolumn in anywhere before the column I have set this up for, will I need to go in and alter the code to work again?

Comment: Also, If i want to add another button like this in another row to do the same thing but with different cells, what will have to change to have the 2 codes running without name clash etc? I have tried copying it and pasting it below, and changing the column etc, but then neither work and it says there is a routine name issue, so I am assuming they need different sub routine names. Whaich part of the name do I change to avoid clashes please?

Comment: *If I add a column...will I need to go in and alter the code?* Yes. VBA code doesn't get updated when you change the structure of a worksheet. The code will look at column `B` as long as that's how the code is written.

Comment: *If i want to add another button like this in another row to do the same thing but with different cells* I edited my answer to provide a method for having two button columns, each able to behave differently in their copy actions. You could copy the new code blocks for as many button column/copy column combinations as you like. Be sure to upvote if this answer has helped.

Comment: Sir, absolutely fantastic and very much appreciated. You are a star. Thank you so much for your time...

Comment: Hey Twisty, Unfortunately, that appeasr to have disabled double click everywhere else on the document, which means I am unable to edit any other field, and i absolutely need to be able to do this. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Mark, the code as it appears in my answer cancels the double-click only inside the two `IF...END IF` blocks, and their code is only executed when the user double-clicks in one of the "button columns." Check your code to confirm you have the `Cancel = True` statement(s) in the correct location.